# Asynchronous stomp consumer without using twisted framework in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm trying to port some of my old code which used `stompest` to query a stomp activemq queue and put it into a queue, into an asynchronous one.
The examples in stompest uses twisted framework, which is not something I wish to go for. What I'm looking for is a function which will asynchronously fetch data from a MQ and put it into a local asyncio.Queue as long as its `maxsize` is not full. I'll be writing other functions which will take data from the local queue and do some network queries asynchronously on them and return the data to another MQ.

```
def message_queue_reader():
    from stompest.config import StompConfig
    from stompest.protocol import StompSpec
    from stompest.sync import Stomp

    CONFIG = StompConfig(ACTIVEMQ['server'])
    QUEUE = ACTIVEMQ['tx-queue']

    DOMINIQUEUE = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=100)

    client = Stomp(CONFIG)
    client.connect()
    client.subscribe(QUEUE, {StompSpec.ACK_HEADER: StompSpec.ACK_CLIENT_INDIVIDUAL})
    while not DOMINIQUEUE.full():
        # this is the code section i wish to make asynchronous
        frame = client.receiveFrame()
        DOMINIQUEUE.put(frame)
        client.ack(frame)
        # end
    client.disconnect()
```

Can this be done without twisted? I'm running python3.5